# Azure: Copy a VM: No storageProfile

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, clone

I'm using the information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/upload-vhd) to copy a VM on Azure. I'm unable to get past the first step as my storage profile is coming back empty. I get nothing from the command below. If I remove the query, it displays my VM info. Querying for just `storageProfile` also doesn't print anything.

```
az vm show -n myVM -g myRG --query "storageProfile.osDisk.unmanagedDisk.id"
```

My VM has a blob based VHD. Wondering if I'm barking up the wrong tree. Pardon my ignorance as I'm quite new to Azure and the amount of information out there is a bit overwhelming.

Comment: Do you want to copy an existing VM? and this is a unmanaged disk?

Comment: That is correct Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My VM has a blob based VHD.

According to your description, your VM create with Azure blob, unmanaged disk.
Unmanaged disk VM information like this, there is **no** unmanaged property:

```
"osDisk": {
      "caching": "ReadWrite",
      "createOption": "fromImage",
      "diskSizeGb": null,
      "encryptionSettings": null,
      "image": null,
      "managedDisk": null,
      "name": "jasonvm",
      "osType": "Linux",
      "vhd": {
        "uri": "https://vmdisks909.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/jasonvm20170727093048.vhd"
      }
    }
```

So we can use this script to show the VHD uri information:

```
az vm show -g vm -n jasonvm --query "storageProfile.osDisk.vhd.uri" -o tsv
```

Also, if you want to copy this VHD to another Azure storage account, we can use this script:

```
# Copy blob from source account to destination account (destcontainer must exist)
az storage blob copy start \
    --account-name destaccountname \
    --account-key destaccountkey \
    --destination-blob destfile.vhd \
    --destination-container destcontainer \
    --source-uri https://sourceaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/sourcecontainer/sourcefile.vhd
```

More information about copy blob to another container, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-azure-cli#manage-storage-accounts).

Comment: I'm unable to authenticate my copy command now even though I have a valid access key. It's asking for an `Authorization` header which I'd hope the cli would take care of? `Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.`

Comment: Downloading the blob isn't working for me either as it's in use. `This blob is being used by the system.`. Will shutting down the VM make it downloadable? I can't seem to figure out another way to disconnect it. I just need to clone the server so need to be able to bring everything back up as is.

Comment: @AnshulKoka because this vhd in used, we should shutdown this VM, and copy it:)

Comment: @AnshulKoka By the way, if you want to copy this VHD to create another VM, we should prepare it, then use this new VHD to create new VMs.

Comment: @AnshulKoka To prepare this VHD, we can follow this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/classic/create-upload-vhd  We should backup this VHD, then prepare this.

Comment: @AnshulKoka Does this work for you? please let me know if you need further assistance:)

Comment: Thanks Jason. The information was definitely helpful but unfortunately I can't take down my production server to go through with the imaging process. I'm going to have to create a new VM to verify this.